# How to prevent one tag from disrupting the centering of another

Tags: html, css, button

I have two tags within a div that has `text-align: center;` attached to it. The problem is that I am trying to have one of them centered on the same line, and where the other one is next to it going further to the right. What is happening is that they are both sharing the centered space and going equally out right and left. Sadly, I cannot remove the text-align: center; and I cannot determine the width of either tag.

Here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/darrow8/pen/ZgYWrw

Comment: Are you allowed to edit the html part? Like add a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this short and simple approach,
Using flexbox and position absolute.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>CENTERED </h4>
  <button>LEANING RIGHT</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
 }

button{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

[Screenshot of code in working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qjBf.png)

Checkout demo on Codepen
https://codepen.io/junaydk/full/YmPWJL

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to go for something like this?

```
<div style="background-color:grey;text-align: center; position: relative">
  <h4 style="display:block">CENTERED</h4>
  <button style="position:relative; left: 50px;">LEANING RIGHT</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you must wrap the two with an `inline-block` element, to make sure that the wrapper will not take the whole width of its parent. Adjust the value of `translate()` as necessary. The other one is for comparison

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate(25%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:grey;text-align: center;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h4 style="display:inline-block">CENTERED </h4>
    <button>LEANING RIGHT</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="background-color:grey;text-align: center;">
  <h4 style="display:inline-block">CENTERED </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must give a tag (that has some text) a `height` property and then you give `line-hight` property same value as `height` property as you set ..
see example blow :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        /* --  rest css first -- */
        *{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        h2{
            margin: 5px auto;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.62);
            font-family: Tahoma;
        }
        .box1{
            width: fit-content;
            height: 200px;
            /*this is for text to be center of the box*/
            line-height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            /*----------------------------------------*/
            background-color: #5548ff;
            margin:10px auto;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .box2{
            width: fit-content;
            height: 300px;
            /*this is for text to be center of the box*/
            line-height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
            /*----------------------------------------*/
            background-color: rgba(255, 46, 81, 0.76);
            margin:10px auto;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>in these boxs height=line-hight for text to be center of the box</h2>
       <div class="box1">
           this text is center of the box
       </div>
       <div class="box2">
           this text is center of the box
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code will help you.

```
button {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
```